# Не перемещается окно за элемент grid в gride

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

Имеется такой код:

```
<Window x:Class="ChatClientWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChatClientWPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"

    Panel.ZIndex="0"
    Title="ChatClient" Height="450" Width="800"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None">

<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="130" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0"
          MouseLeftButtonDown="Caption_MouseLeftButtonDown">

    </Grid >
</Grid>
```

```
private void Caption_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DragMove();
    }
```

Если добавить параметр *MouseLeftButtonDown="Caption_MouseLeftButtonDown"* в Window тогда окно будет перемещаться, а когда он находится в grid форма не перемещается. Как сделать, что бы за grid окно перемещалось

Comment: я ничего не понял, что куда добавляется, что перемещается, в чем прблема. Можете переформулировать вопрос?

Comment: Зажимая мышкой в области Grid у которого параметр MouseLeftButtonDown="Caption_MouseLeftButtonDown" и перемещая ее, окно должно перемещаться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте `Background` для `Grid`, можно даже прозрачный.

```xaml
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="Caption_MouseLeftButtonDown">
</Grid>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло. Странно конечно, не когда не встречал такого. Есть какая нибудь статья на эту тему?

Comment: @helldrg Не за что. Статей не читал, я интуитивно, экспериментально подобрал решение.